# Reduce output volume on shutdown

Tags: macos, shutdown

Running Mojave 10.14.6. I'd like to alter my output volume upon shutdown, so that it when it starts it's always at the same volume (20%). This would make the "DAHHH!" sound more pleasant, but it's also so that app sounds present in a consistent and predictable way.

I couldn't understand how to run a script upon regular shutdown trigger (complicated) but I made an AppleScript to change volume and then shutdown, i.e. to replace the regular shutdown trigger:

```
set volume output volume 20
tell application "Finder" to shut down
```

I saved that as an app and it seemed to work great until I realised it was reopening upon login every time, thus shutting the machine down again! I booted in safe mode to clear the open apps and breathed a huge sigh of relief.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve my goal? I don't really want to disable the "dahhh!" because it's useful for troubleshooting. I'd like the regular app sounds to start at a consistent volume by default. I literally just want to "reset" the volume to 20% every time I turn off.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager) to do this. An included **Set volume at log out** task will do what you want. Logging out is part of the shut down process.

[image: Set volume on log out using Power Manager on macOS]

I work on Power Manager, so feel free to ask technical questions about how it works in the comments.